# populate empty submitted results mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, populate, is-empty

I was wondering if anyone can help this beginner programmer..
I have a script that selects and displays the results below:

**1** **hello**  //*empty*

**2** **hello**  //*empty*

**3** **hello**

**4**

**5**

results 1,2 are empty infact, as it says on the right.

the ***hello*** *4,5* has gone up the hill...

here is what I have in script:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT value from afp_data_fields WHERE field_id='1' ") or die 

    ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());?>

<?php  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {  

echo '<table>';

echo'<tr>';

echo '<td>'.$row['value'].'</td>';

echo '</tr>';

}       

echo '</table>';
```

I thank you rich soul for your most important help.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the data in your MySQL database?? Also - you will want to put the: `echo '<table>';` Before the loop, that will muck up how your results are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php

echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{  
  echo '<tr><td>';
  echo ($row['value']!="")?$row['value']:"Not Filled";
  echo '</td></tr>';
} 
echo '</table>';
```

[image: issue you are facing]

Your Code

```
<table style="font-size:11px">
<tr>dano_grave</tr>
<tr>sem_dano</tr>
<tr>dano_moderado</tr‌​>
<tr>dano_moderado</tr>
</table>
```

Altered:

```
<table style="font-size:11px">
<tr><td>dano_grave</td></tr>
<tr><td>sem_dano</td></tr>
<tr><td>dano_moderado</td></tr‌​>
<tr><td>dano_moderado</td></tr>
</table>
```

For more info please refer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: no errors everything fine, as I mentioned the field results are moving to the empty spaces above..

Comment: give your html result for my better understand

Comment: when I fetch the data column everything displays fine, your tip to move table tag up works well thank you. but still there are fields in which the user submitted empty, how do I put something like "NOT FILLED" instead of leaving it blank?

Comment: try to print the values print_r($row); inside the while for check the values

Comment: values are there and visible, still horizontal

Comment: this is simple if condition .. ($row['name']!="")?$row['name']:"Not Filled"  this results if the row value is not empty prints the value from db else our custom text not filled surely printed . did u get or not . your db values are not empty string maybe

Comment: I have on my screen these strings     dano_graveArray ( [0] => dano_grave [value] => dano_grave ) sem_danoArray ( [0] => sem_dano [value] => sem_dano ) dano_moderadoArray ( [0] => dano_moderado [value] => dano_moderado ) dano_moderadoArray ( [0] => dano_moderado [value] => dano_moderado )

Comment: i need your generated html dom node. inspect your result page by firebug(mozilla extension) and copy the html element code of that table .

Comment: ok,   <table style="font-size:11px"><tr>dano_grave</tr><tr>sem_dano</tr><tr>dano_moderado</tr><tr>dano_moderado</tr></table>

Comment: <td></td> tag missing on your html

Comment: your table must be like <table style="font-size:11px"><tr><td>dano_grave</td></tr><tr><td>sem_dano</td></tr><tr><td>dano_moderado</td></tr‌​><tr><td>dano_moderado</td></tr></table>

Comment: i edit agin on my post . i found your problem . you are missing the td tag . use the edited post code . it will resolved .

Comment: ok saw your code: now I get this: <table><tr><td>Not Filled</td></tr><tr><td>Not Filled</td></tr><tr><td>Not Filled</td></tr><tr><td>Not Filled</td></tr></table>

Comment: not filled not appear that string have some characters (that means u have value in DB)

Comment: the goal is to make it appear, so it fills the blank and lower results won't move up.

Comment: Mr. Ryan, maybe I didn't explain well.. there are two blank entries in the database, these entries I want to see them as Not Filled. thank you so kind sir.

Comment: Blank entries are selected or not. You give a $row array have values. There are four rows there. All rows have values.if the $row['value'] is empty the above code will effect correctly. check sql and results that are passed on while loop . how many rows are selected by your query

Comment: Im sorry Mr.Ryan, there are 7 entries in my mysql database four (the ones you see) have values, the remaing 3 entries have no values therefore are blanks, how may I see these blanks as Not Filled?

Comment: run this query on your phpmyadmin SELECT value from afp_data_fields WHERE field_id='1'

Comment: ok. query successful    I can see al the full_names from the database. & names.

Comment: print result on your question itself

Comment: Hello sir Ryan, i have printed with success, but only 4 entries, there are 3 more that are blank entries, these I want to print as well with Not Filled text.